# Django ManyToOne?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have an inventory management application, and inside is an `Item()` class that represents the product. All of the devices will be serialized so there will be a class later that represents each device called `OnHand()`.

**Item Model**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    introduction = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    quanity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_retired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def add(self):
        pass

    def remove(self):
        pass

    def retire(self): # Rex came up with this, roll credits.
        pass 

    def count(self):
        pass
```

I want an attribute for **on_hand** that has a **ManyToOne** type relationship.

**OnHand Model Concept**

```
class OnHand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharFiled(max_length=100)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serial
```

When creating a new **OnHand** object, I'd like to associate it with the **Item**. How would I go about doing this?

**Structural Example**

- Item

  - Name = MacBook Pro
  - Description = 15.5" MacBook Pro
  - OnHand

    - serial number, asset tag
    - serial number, asset tag
    - serial number, asset tag

**Current Test Code**

```
def make_macbook():
    """ Create a Manufacturer for Apple """
    apple = Manufacturer(name='Apple', rep_name='Jason Wilburn', support_number='1-800-Apple')
    apple.save()
    print('Manufacturer name: {}'.format(apple))

    """ Create a Category for Laptops """
    laptop = Category(name='Laptops')
    laptop.save()
    print('Category name: {}'.format(laptop))

    """ Create a Tag for Mac """
    mac = Tag(title='mac')
    mac.save()
    print('Tag name: {}'.format(mac))

    """ Create a MacBook Item """
    macbook = Item(name='Macbook Pro', description='15.5" Macbook Pro, 2018 Model', manufacturer=apple)
    macbook.save()
    print('Item name: {}'.format(macbook))

    """ Create a MacBook OnHand item """
    newMac = OnHand(name='MacBook Pro 15.5"', serial='SC02XP0NRJGH5', asset='DEPSC02XP0NRJGH5', product=macbook)
    newMac.save()

    """ Add to Item's OnHand """
```

Now I'm mainly just stuck on adding to the **Item()** OnHand to create the relationship.

Comment: Why not just add Foreign key from OnHand to item? wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: Could you write up an example for me? I'm still learning, so these "obvious" fundamental solutions still get very lost on me. This is also my first entry into any form of 'complex' relational stuff.

Comment: Sure, added below as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a foreign key from your OnHand model to the Item model to achieve this. When you create an OnHand object, you just tie it to the required Item object.

```
class OnHand(models.Model):
   name = models.CharFiled(max_length=100)
   serial = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.serial
```

Then in your view, when creating an OnHand object,

```
...
""" Create a MacBook Item """
macbook = Item(name='Macbook Pro', description='15.5" Macbook Pro, 2018 Model', manufacturer=apple)
macbook.save()
print('Item name: {}'.format(macbook))

""" Create a MacBook OnHand item """
newMac = OnHand(name='MacBook Pro 15.5"', serial='SC02XP0NRJGH5', asset='DEPSC02XP0NRJGH5', product=macbook, item=macbook)
newMac.save()
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow so this is exactly what I had done out of instinct but thought it was incorrect. Good to know I'm just suffering from "overthinking", thanks for the help!

Comment: Add to your answer, though, for future readers:
`product = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

`on_delete` is required, and allowing it to be `null` prevents any issues if the product doesn't yet exist and is being created from this OnHand instance.

Comment: Yes the above is true, but careful with the nulls and blanks, these are often used as a DB level validation, as such when one record depends on the other before being , such as the case when you are creating a UserProfile for a User, where in this case you canT allow a UserProfile to be created without it being related to a User.

Comment: Ah fair enough, and the onhand does absolutely rely on the item/product existing. I'll have to just write logic for when adding onhand while adding a product.